# Triggering events and binding in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to jQuery and have been playing around with it. This is what I have:

```
<fieldset id="question-7">
  <p>
    <label>Question 7</label>
  </p>
  <p>
    We need a custom event named "profileUpdated". Bind to this event and make the word "Updated" appear in the output div when triggered.
    Trigger the event when this <a href="#">link</a> is clicked.
  </p>
  <p class="output">
  </p>
</fieldset>
```

and my jQuery is:

```
function profileUpdated() {
  $( "#question-7" ).bind( "link", function() {
    alert( $( this ).text('Updated') );
  });
});
```

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: To answer the question what you are doing wrong, we need to know what you are trying to do. There is no such event "link".

Comment: I am trying to trigger the event profileUpdated when I click on the link. When I click the link I want Updated to appear in the output div. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First of all there is **no event** called **"link"** as @dfsq said, but  **For more flexible event binding**
you can use **.on()**  or **.delegate()**

example :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#question-7').on('click',function(){
        alert($(this).text());
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#link").on( "profileUpdated", function( e ) {
        $(".output").html("Updated");
    });

    $("#link").click(function() {
        $( this ).trigger( "profileUpdated" );
    });
});
```

Comment: Why do you need two event handlers?

Comment: As per the requirement stated in the question, "profileUpdated" event should be triggered on click of 'link' anchor tag.

Comment: you can simply put   `$(".output").html("Updated")` inside `$('#link').clik()` ant that's it

Comment: You may have a point Kumar, although if the idea is to make `profileUpdated` events separate from `link`/`click` events then it doesn't make sense for `profileUpdated` to be on the link.

Comment: @hamism agreed. But, as per Nellinel's description, he has some requirement which needs him to trigger the 'profileUpdated' event on click of the link. And only when the 'profileUpdated' event gets triggered, the text 'Updated' should be added inside the output block.

Comment: @DavidKnipe I guess you are right. May be 'profileUpdated' can be bound to the 'p.output' block.

Comment: That's not what I meant. I meant the event emitter shouldn't even be an HTML element.